# Does it makes sense to consider Monitoring of applications a part of Sub Domain under Domain Driven Design?

Tags: domain-driven-design, subdomain, banking

We are creating a system that will take care of Loan Origination.
We have been taking the Domain-Driven Design approach from the start.
We are at a stage where we are working on to identify subdomains and context map.

The interesting part is that one of our business use case itself is to maintain uptime of the system 24/7 with 360-degree monitoring.

Does it make sense to add application Monitoring as part of Sub Domains?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, it does. Once a domain expert requests a feature and pays for it, it should be on a context map as a core/supporting/generic domain.

Generally, if a feature is used by a business user (not a developer or DevOps) it should be in the context map. There is a high probability of more features in this domain in the future, like reports, subscription plans and so on.